# Use of Group By affects average

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-server-2014

This is a little puzzling to me, so I'm hoping someone can help make sense of it. I have the following query that gets me the average quantity over the last 180 days.

```
SELECT 'TOTAL', AVG(M.LAST_QTY_SHIP_BASE)
FROM PS_IN_DEMAND M
WHERE M.DEMAND_DATE > DATEADD(d, -180, GETDATE())
AND M.INV_ITEM_ID = 1
AND M.BUSINESS_UNIT = 'WEST1'
```

This returns a single row with the value **6.1919**

If I add a **GROUP BY** condition to the above query - `GROUP BY M.DEMAND_DATE` then I get the entire result set of average quantities based on the date range (127 rows). If I average all of these values in Excel I am getting an average of **6.3980**. I'm just curious why the averages are not the same? Am I getting averages of the groups, vs. the values? Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Sample data (With GROUP BY M.DEMAND_DATE)

```
(No column name)    (No column name)  DEMAND_DATE
TOTAL                 10.000000       2017-12-15 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 5.500000        2017-12-18 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 8.000000        2017-12-19 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 6.000000        2017-12-20 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 8.000000        2017-12-21 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 15.500000       2017-12-22 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 8.000000        2017-12-26 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 11.500000       2017-12-27 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 6.000000        2017-12-29 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 2.000000        2017-12-30 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 4.333333        2018-01-02 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 2.000000        2018-01-03 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 8.000000        2018-01-04 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 5.333333        2018-01-05 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 3.000000        2018-01-08 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 7.000000        2018-01-09 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 6.500000        2018-01-10 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 4.000000        2018-01-12 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 1.000000        2018-01-13 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 1.000000        2018-01-14 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 8.000000        2018-01-15 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 8.000000        2018-01-16 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 10.000000       2018-01-17 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 7.500000        2018-01-18 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 4.000000        2018-01-19 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 8.000000        2018-01-22 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 4.250000        2018-01-23 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 2.666666        2018-01-24 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 8.000000        2018-01-25 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 7.333333        2018-01-26 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 6.000000        2018-01-29 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 8.000000        2018-01-30 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 5.000000        2018-01-31 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 5.000000        2018-02-02 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 6.000000        2018-02-05 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 14.000000       2018-02-06 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 3.000000        2018-02-07 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 6.000000        2018-02-08 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 6.000000        2018-02-09 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 3.000000        2018-02-12 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 14.000000       2018-02-13 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 6.000000        2018-02-14 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 10.000000       2018-02-15 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 5.500000        2018-02-16 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 7.500000        2018-02-19 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 1.750000        2018-02-20 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 7.000000        2018-02-21 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 14.000000       2018-02-22 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 3.000000        2018-02-23 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 10.000000       2018-02-26 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 11.000000       2018-02-27 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 10.000000       2018-02-28 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 4.666666        2018-03-02 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 2.000000        2018-03-03 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 2.000000        2018-03-04 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 2.666666        2018-03-05 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 10.000000       2018-03-06 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 8.500000        2018-03-07 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 6.000000        2018-03-08 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 4.000000        2018-03-09 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 10.000000       2018-03-12 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 1.000000        2018-03-13 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 14.000000       2018-03-14 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 8.000000        2018-03-15 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 10.000000       2018-03-16 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 2.000000        2018-03-18 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 14.000000       2018-03-20 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 10.000000       2018-03-21 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 5.000000        2018-03-23 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 2.000000        2018-03-24 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 5.500000        2018-03-26 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 14.000000       2018-03-27 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 10.500000       2018-03-28 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 2.500000        2018-03-30 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 1.500000        2018-04-02 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 9.000000        2018-04-03 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 4.000000        2018-04-04 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 10.000000       2018-04-05 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 6.000000        2018-04-06 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 6.000000        2018-04-09 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 7.500000        2018-04-10 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                13.500000        2018-04-11 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 2.000000        2018-04-12 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 2.800000        2018-04-13 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 8.500000        2018-04-16 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 8.000000        2018-04-17 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 3.000000        2018-04-18 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                14.000000        2018-04-19 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 4.000000        2018-04-20 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 2.000000        2018-04-21 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 2.000000        2018-04-23 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 2.000000        2018-04-24 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                10.000000        2018-04-25 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 4.666666        2018-04-27 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 4.000000        2018-04-29 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 5.000000        2018-04-30 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 9.500000        2018-05-01 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 4.000000        2018-05-02 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 1.000000        2018-05-03 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 3.333333        2018-05-04 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 3.500000        2018-05-07 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 9.500000        2018-05-08 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 5.333333        2018-05-09 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 2.000000        2018-05-10 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 6.000000        2018-05-14 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                14.000000        2018-05-15 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 8.000000        2018-05-16 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 7.000000        2018-05-17 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 5.000000        2018-05-18 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 2.000000        2018-05-19 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 5.000000        2018-05-21 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                14.000000        2018-05-22 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 7.000000        2018-05-23 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 6.000000        2018-05-24 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 2.000000        2018-05-26 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 6.750000        2018-05-29 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 5.500000        2018-05-31 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                10.000000        2018-06-01 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 2.000000        2018-06-03 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 8.000000        2018-06-04 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 2.000000        2018-06-05 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 5.000000        2018-06-06 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 7.333333        2018-06-07 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 5.333333        2018-06-08 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 2.000000        2018-06-10 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                10.000000        2018-06-11 00:00:00.000
TOTAL                 4.500000        2018-06-12 00:00:00.000
```

If you average all the values in the 2nd column I get 6.3980, instead of 6.1919 without use of the Group By.

Comment: What is in your GROUP BY? It may be combining non-unique rows.

Comment: Only what I have above... `GROUP BY M.DEMAND_DATE`

Comment: Are you certain that all your dates are unique and there are no nulls?

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115091/is-the-average-of-the-averages-equal-to-the-average-of-all-the-numbers-originall) from math.stackexchange. Average of average may not equal to average of all.

Comment: Yes they appear to be unique and there are no null values. I added a `Distinct` clause and this did not change the row count.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data?

Comment: But why did you ignore the post by @FarzanMirheydari with the answer to your question? Lol... I'll copy and paste it: `The correct answer is that it depends. The average of averages is only equal to the average of all values in two cases:

if the number of elements of all groups is the same or
the trivial case when all the group averages are zero`

Comment: I edited the post and provided the sample data above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thorsten is correct, but it is worth a bit more explanation.

When you run:

```
SELECT 'TOTAL', AVG(M.LAST_QTY_SHIP_BASE)
. . .;
```

You are getting the average over *all* the data.  Each row in your original data is weighted exactly once.

When you run:

```
SELECT M.DEMAND_DATE, AVG(M.LAST_QTY_SHIP_BASE), COUNT(*) as cnt
. . .
GROUP BY M.DEMAND_DATE;
```

You are bringing together groups of records -- on the same date -- and then treating them as a single value.  That is, you are weighting by *days* rather than by the original *rows*.

If you had 10 records and 9 were on, say, Jan 1 and 1 was on Jan 2, then the first method treats each record equally.  The second treats the Jan 2 record as being 9x the value of the first.  So, if the values were "1" on Jan 1 and "2" on Jan 2, the two averages would be:

- (9 + 2) / 10 = 1.1  -- weighted by records
- (1 + 2) / 2  = 1.5  -- weighted by days

Both are appropriate averages.  Perhaps another way of looking at this is that about 16% or so of the world population speaks Mandarin.  Only about 1% of the countries speak Mandarin (it is the official language in Singapore and China).  The two numbers are not the same, because countries have different sizes.

Comment: Thank you, that example helps and I can now more clearly distinguish the two methods. It really all depends on how the business requirement for average is defined.

Answer (score 1):

The average of the averages is not necessarily the total average. (In fact it's even rarely the case.)

Sample data:

```
day1   20
day1   20
day2   80
```

results:

```
total average: (20 + 20 + 80) / 3 = 40

day1 average: (20 + 20) / 2 = 20
day2 average: 80 / 1 = 80

average of the averages: (20 + 80) / 2 = 50
```

Comment: So in my case, is the GROUP BY essentially averaging the averages?

Comment: @Nick - no, _you're_ doing the average-of-average, via Excel.  What it's doing is providing the separated list of overages.